# iphone - UIColor leaking... need to release the object?

Tags: iphone

I have a bunch of lines like this on my app

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:corR green:corG blue:corB alpha:1.0];
```

Instruments are saying these lines are leaking. As this is not formally, as far as I see, an alloc operation (isn't it?) I don't saw the need to release the object, but as instruments are complaining, I added several lines as

```
[myColor release]
```

after using the variable, to please the beast.

Will I have problems doing this, like crashes or something?

Apparently doing this is solving the problem, but I am not comfortable to release an object that was not allocated.

What do you think?

thanks.

---

### **E D I T**

I suppose this is a xcode problem or a framework leak.
To prove that I replace the lines with

```
UIColor *myColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:corR green:corG blue:corB alpha:1.0];
```

and then the object could be safely released...

doing that, solved the problem.

Comment: You are right, you should not have to release that line. Something else in you code is the culprit. What else does Instruments point to?

Comment: instrument points to this lines... every line I used this is marked as leaking and I am not retaining. If I am not wrong I don't have any retain command in my entire project. I have a second option: replacing these lines with [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed: green: blue: alpha:]... then I can release it.

Comment: Since colors are actually special (basically singletons), UIColor is almost certainly just doing some kind of caching. Unless your app is being jettisoned all the time due to the memory being used by UIColor's caching, I would just ignore it. Letting UIColor cache will speed up your access to colors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't release the object, you don't own it and you will eventually get crashes. UIColor is probably just caching these colors for you, and Instruments has no way of knowing this so it reports them as leaks (basically stuff that got created and you don't have a reference to anymore but hasn't been deallocated).

Try running instruments for some time (using the simulator) and then sending a memory warning to see if UIColor will purge its cache. Either way, there isn't anything you can really do to fix leaks happening inside core frameworks, so don't try. Just make sure you're not actually leaking them somehow (like retaining them at some point and never releasing them).

Comment: thanks. Please read the comment I wrote on my question, answering to Jason McCreary...

Answer (score 2):

If that's all you are doing, `myColor` is most definitely not leaking. If you are retaining that object anywhere else without releasing it, it is leaking.

Never release an object that you don't remember retaining. ***Evvarrrrrrrrr***. But I suspect that you just are retaining it somewhere, and don't even notice it.

Comment: thanks. Please read the comment I wrote on my question, answering to Jason McCreary...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the simulator can report leaks when there are none, make sure to also see if you get the same leak on the device as well...

But since it's faster to work with the simulator, try finding things there first.