# UIColor Memory Leak Issue

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been trying to solve this issue. Basically I am using the convenience RGB UIColor function to return a UIColor to tint my UINavigationBar, UIToolbar and other objects. However for some reason in Instruments it keeps on saying I have a memory leak every time I load a UIView. Any help would be appreciated. I have simplified the code here for clarity purposes. Here is my function (the function has the RGB and Alpha as variables) which is located in a Global singleton class:

```
- (UIColor *)returnSelectedColor{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(100)/255.0 green:(100)/255.0 blue:(100)/255.0 alpha:(1.0)];
}
```

In my RootViewController I set this in the ViewWillAppear (sometimes tint can change in between calls however I tried ViewDidLoad but the problem was still there). I tried two different approaches to solve this issue but leak is still present.

The first approach was just to set the tint when view appears like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[[GlobalData sharedGlobalData] returnSelectedNavigationColor];
```

The second approach was to create a UIColor property for the view, set it to desired UIColor, and then set the navigationbar tint to this property, when view closes I release the property. This approach also causes a memory leak. Here is the code:

```
    if(self.navigationToolbarColor!=nil){
        [self.navigationToolbarColor release];
    }
    self.navigationToolbarColor=[[[GlobalData sharedGlobalData] returnSelectedNavigationColor] retain];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=self.navigationToolbarColor;
```

Anybody have an idea on what the issue may be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you likely have `navigationToolbarColor` as a retained property, so you're over-retaining on this line:

```
self.navigationToolbarColor=[[[GlobalData sharedGlobalData] returnSelectedNavigationColor] retain];
```

Get rid of the call to `retain` there and you should be all good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I tried that however I still get the same memory leak. The first approach I used doesn't have a retain (without a property) and gives a memory leak. I tried using the property without retains as you suggested and that also gives a memory leak. I just thought of something, could this be because my function is in a singleton object?

Comment: No, that wasn't it. I tried doing this directly instead of calling a function and still get a memory leak: self.navigationToolbarColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:(39)/255.0 green:(64)/255.0 blue:(139)/255.0 alpha:(1.0)]; Should I release the UIColor somewhere after I assigned it to the tint of the navigation controller? I didn't think that was necessary since its supposed to be an auto-released object. Any clues or ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by basically adding categories to the UIColor object. This creates my custom color objects which stay in memory. This way when I set my tint in my different objects in different views I don't get any more memory leaks. Here is some sample code if anybody encounters the same issue.

Here is the CustomColors.h file

```
#define RGBCOLOR(r,g,b,a) [UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255.0 green:(g)/255.0 blue:(b)/255.0 alpha:(a)]

@interface UIColor (CustomColors)

+ (UIColor *)standardColor:(int)selectedAlpha;

@end
```

Here is the CustomColors.m file

```
#import "CustomColors.h"

@implementation UIColor (CustomColors)

    + (UIColor *)standardColor{
        static UIColor *customColor = nil;

        if (!customColor){
            customColor = RGBCOLOR(135,153,188,1.0);
            [customColor retain];
        }
        return customColor;
    }
```

Then after including the #import "CustomColors.h" in all my views I can assign my colors like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor standardColor];
```

@end

And that is it. Now you can enjoy UIColors without the memory leaks.

Comment: Very strongly recommend against this solution.  See answer my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The static solution is definitely NOT what you want to do.  You're fixing a false positive problem with a REAL problem that way.  See the solution to [iphone - UIColor leaking... need to release the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868742/iphone-uicolor-leaking-need-to-release-the-object)

Just don't worry about the "leak" and you're fine.