# drawRect method causing leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, ios4

I have one leak issue in my application, i am creating a autorelease object of color but says by intrument that problem is there.

```
Malloc  1   04:12.221.102   32  UIKit   +[UIColor allocWithZone:]
Autorelease <null>  04:12.221.107   0   TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1   -[UINavigationBar(CustomImage) drawRect:]
Retain  2   04:12.221.125   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationBar setTintColor:]
Release 1   04:12.226.279   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
Retain  2   04:18.697.490   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationButton setTintColor:]
Retain  3   07:35.584.218   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationBar setTintColor:]
Release 2   07:35.584.225   0   TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1   -[UINavigationBar(CustomImage) drawRect:]
Release 1   08:30.378.434   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationButton setTintColor:]
```

This is my code

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"toolbar_bkg.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

    self.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.913 green:0.725 blue:0.070 alpha:1.000]; //Yellow color
}
@end
```

I hope you guys find the problem I am not able to find till now.

Comment: Can you show the code for tintColor declaration?

Comment: @PeterKelly `tintColor` is a property of UINavigationBar.

Comment: @Caleb Yes of course it is, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have nothing to worry about. You shouldn't be worried about releasing UIColor as you do not own it anyway. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868742/iphone-uicolor-leaking-need-to-release-the-object)